# Create Hidden Fields in User Profile

Tags: drupal-7

I've successfully created a custom user field using the code referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579350/how-to-add-new-fields-to-user-profile-in-drupal-7-programmatically).

I'd like the field to be formatted "Hidden" per the Account Settings page. I've set the type to hidden on the field instance but it's not hiding. Any idea how to **program** this field as hidden in my module?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [Field Permissions module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

You can configure the field appearance the way you want.

Hope that helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Is there a function that the Field Permissions module provides to hide a field? I'm specifically looking to programmatically create a field and create an instance of it that is hidden.

Answer (score -2):

You can use hidden field module

Comment: Using the hidden field module does not solve this problem. I tested it.